# using two classes in java

Tags: java, bluej

I am trying to use two classes **Member class** and **Website class**  to talk to each other. I want to use the code which is in the **setloggedInStatus()** method in the **Member class** and be able to use it in the **memberLogin()** method which is in the **Website class**. I used the `Member memberObject = new setloggedInStatus();`      code but its giving me an error.

I Would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance

Website class

```
public class Website
{
    // declaration of vars 
    private String websiteName;
    private int hits; 
    private double salesTotal; 
    

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Website
     */
    public Website(String websiteName)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
         this.websiteName = websiteName;  
    }
    
   
    Member memberObject = new setloggedInStatus(); 
 
   public void memberLogin() {
       
    
    
    }
}
```

Member class

```
public class Member
{
    // varibales declaration 
    private String email;  
    private int membershipNumber; 
    private boolean loggedInStatus; 

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Member
     */
    public Member(String memberEmail, int newMembershipNumber )
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        email = memberEmail;
        membershipNumber = newMembershipNumber;
    }

    //loggedInStatus method
    public void setloggedInStatus() {
    if (email != null && membershipNumber != 0) {
        loggedInStatus = true;
        System.out.println("you are logged in ");
         
    } 
    
    else {
        loggedInStatus = false;
        System.out.println("you are not logged in");
    }
}
    
  
    }
```

Comment: We don't instanciate methods, we instanciate classes and call its member methods

Comment: If you want to create an object that is an instance of the `Member` class, you should call the `Member` constructor. You don't call setters with the `new` keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to use the functionality of Member inside the class Website, you would need to import it via `import Member` at the top of the Website file (depending on if they're in the same folder/package). This will make it available inside the file.

You could then create a new Member object via `Member member = new Member(`params go here`);`

Then, you could call the methods contained inside your Member class from your created `member` object, for example `member.setLoggedInStatus();`

EDIT: Did this answer your question?

Comment: if the classes are in the same package the import instance is not necessary

Comment: @adilos you're right, i edited the answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

if the Website Class and the Member Class are in the same package you have to create an object of Member like this:

```
String email = "Example@examplemail.com";
int id = 3; //Example id
Member the_member = new Member(email,3);
```

If you want to call the   `public void setloggedInStatus()` method you can simply do something like this with the previous object created:

```
the_member.setloggedInStatus();
```

If the two classes are not in the same package you have to import the class Member with

`import Member`